# <input type="image" ...> com LINK e HOVER

Tags: html, css, link

Não consigo colocar um efeito em um botão, tenho 3 imagens feitas no photoshop, uma que é Normal (Link), outra quando passa o mouse (Hover), e uma quando clica (Actived), porém, não consigo ativar esses efeitos via CSS, segue meu HTML...

```
<input type="image" src="Botao Azul Normal- OK.png" class="botao">
```

E o css...

```
.botao:hover{background-image: url('Botao Azul Hover - OK.png');
```

}

Imagens:
[image: NORMAL]
[image: HOVER]
[image: Actived]

Não fiz ainda o Actived...

Infelizmente, o efeito Hover não funciona, o botão até aparece, mas via HTML, queria fazer via CSS também...

---

Eu consegui botar para funcionar Chrome e FireFox e rodou, meu problema é que no IE não funciona, e na empresa usam o IE8.

Comment: Você está usando as mesmas imagens, não vai dar pra ver o efeito. Além disso, é necessário definir as propriedades `height` e `width` pra usar o `background-image`.

Comment: Mil desculpas, copiei errado, o <input type="image" src="Botao Azul Hover- OK.png" class="botao"> está <input type="image" src="Botao Azul Normal- OK.png" class="botao">, coloquei errado aqui, mas o erro persisti... desatenção minha, irei corrigir

Comment: OBS: Eu queria fazer tudo no CSS, queria o HTML somente para "estrutura", até o Background Normal(Link) fosse nele...

Comment: Por favor, prefira [edit] a pegunta para corrigir ou adicionar informações. Não esqueça de dar feedbak pras respostas dadas, atualizando a pergunta se necessário. E, dica final: não vale converter a pergunta em outra coisa, se o problema virar outro, faça uma nova pegunta. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema de não funcionar no Explorer era simples, faltava o `<!DOCTYPE html>`, o chrome e o firefox rodava numa boa sem ele, mas o IE não tinha jeito... coloquem o `<!DOCTYPE html>` que o problema fica resolvido.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: coloquem o quê afinal?

Comment: Foi mau, não vi que não tinha aparecido.

Comment: Ok assim já dá para perceber já alterei o down para up :)

Answer (score 3):

Podes alcançar o pretendido da seguinte maneira:

```
<input type="button" class="botao">

.botao {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfGe4.png");
    height:35px;
    width:90px;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    -moz-outline:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.botao:hover {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5lJg.png");
}
.botao:active {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwIyJ.png");
}
```

[**Demo no Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Uy5p/)

**Informação adicional:**
Podes encontrar [nesta página](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/button-tag-in-IE) a razão pela qual é preferível usar `<input>` em vez de `<button>`, possivelmente deve ser essa a razão pela qual não estavas a ter sucesso com o código sugerido pelo @beterraba , poderias estar a ver o resultado do código modificado pelo IE, e o IE em termos de exibir páginas de código é muito rigoroso no que toca a erros e novos parâmetros de código que navegadores mais recentes aceitam.

Answer (score 3):

Voce deve usar o type="submit" para poder estilizar com css.
Usando type="image" voce precisa do "src".

Por exemplo:

HTML

```
<input type="submit" class="botao" value="">
```

CSS

```
.botao
{
background: url('img/image.png')  no-repeat;
width: 100px;  // coloca a largura do botao
height: 100px; // coloca a altura do botao
border: none;
}

.botao:hover
{
background: url('img/image_hover.png')  no-repeat;
}

.botao:active
{ 
background: url('img/image_active.png')  no-repeat;
}

.botao:link
{ 
background: url('img/image_normal.png')  no-repeat;
}

.botao:visited
{ 
background: url('img/image_visited.png')  no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar a propriedade `background-image`, você deve explicitamente setar o tamanho do elemento.

Acredito que seja melhor utilizar a tag `button`, no seu caso:

```
<button class="button"></button>

.button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: transparent;
    background-image: url("botao-normal.png");
    height:35px;
    width:90px;
}

.button:hover {
    background-image: url("botao-hover.png");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aCm45/2/)

Comment: Colocação perfeita! Porém, só funciona o .button, o button:hover não funciona... Coloquei como postou, claro que alterando a classe e a URL

Comment: @Vinithius Não funciona com o `input` por causa do `src="..."`. Retire-o que funciona.

Comment: Estou usando como você fez, <button class="button"></button> mas o HOVER não pega!

Comment: @Vinithius então é provável de que o seu CSS não esteja encontrando o caminho para a imagem, ou o nome esteja incorreto.

Comment: Agradeço a sua ajuda, mas o caminho está certo, a imagem está na mesma pasta do Index.html, simplesmente para não ter erro, mas não foi meu caso...

Comment: O usuário @Beterraba está certo: a imagem em "src" fica acima do background que, portanto, não será visto. A minha dúvida é se a ausência da imagem é aceita na validação de um input type=image.

Answer (score 0):

Só complementando a resposta do @Beterraba, você pode utilizar também webkit.

```
.botao{
  background-image: url(http://www.naturaljoias.com.br/images/botao%20coco%202%20cm%20vermelho.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.botao:hover{
  background-image: url(http://img.mynet.com/ha2/tayyip.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;  
}

.botao:active{
  background-image: url(http://www.pylones.com.br/image/cache/data/produtos/acessorios/suporte-fone-de-ouvido-botao-preto-1-600x600.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e55SP/11/)