# Personalização de botões

Tags: html, css

Colocar botões mais bonitos no lugar dessas setinhas de avançar e voltar.

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="header"><!--
   --><button class="prev go" data-go="-1" disabled>&larr;</button><!--
   --><span class="title">TABELA</span><!--
   --><button class="next go" data-go="1">&rarr;</button><!--
--></div>
```

[image: Modelos_setas]

Comment: Você pode mostrar o seu código todo? Caso contrário fica difícil saber o que vai dar certo para você ou não, ainda mais que o HTML que você postou não corresponde a tabela inteira. Também removi a tag java da sua pergunta porque (pelo menos do jeito que ela está), não tem relação nenhuma com java.

Comment: Minha pergunta foi mudada e com ela todo a ideia proposta, não quero que o botão desapareça, quero que o botão fique lá, pois as pessoas precisam ve-los para clicar e passar para a proxima rodada, seria o que postei no inicio, queria algo mais bonito do que essas duas setinhas.

Comment: Leandro, se você não concorda com a última edição, então o melhor é revertê-la (ou então editar novamente a pergunta para ficar como você acha que é melhor). As edições de conteúdos por aqui nunca deveriam contrariar a vontade de quem criou originalmente tais conteúdos.

Comment: Agradeço, a resposta do @Chun deu certo aqui;realmente com a mudança perdeu o sentido, mas a resposta em cima da pergunta inicial deu certo.

Comment: Leandro, reverti a última alteração na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, respondendo à pergunta da maneira como ela se encontra agora - O `disabled` como o próprio nome o diz, é apenas para desativar/desabilitar um botão/input/etc. Para fazer com que o botão desapareça quando este está desativado, seria preciso adicionar o seguinte estilo CSS:

```
.go[disabled] {
    display:none;
}
```

Aqui selecionamos a class`.go` em vez da `.prev` para que o estilo seja aplicado em ambos os cenários, caso qualquer um dos botões se encontre desativado ele irá aplicar - `display:none;`.

### Respondendo à pergunta original:

Para personalizar estes botões, basta criar o estilo CSS para os mesmos, por exemplo:

```
.go {background-color: royalblue; padding:5px 30px;}
```

No entanto existem certos estilos CSS que não se aplicam a botões `<button>` e/ou também estilos implementados já no navegador por padrão para a tag `button` que teríamos que removê-los para personalizá-los novamente à nossa maneira. Mas podemos sempre contornar isso usando boas práticas como utilizar uma `div/a/span` etc como botão em vez da tag `button`.

Como no exemplo destes botões abaixo criados com a tag `<span>`:

```css
.animate {
    transition: all 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
}

.random-button{
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.go {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #2980B9;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.random-button:active {
    transform: translate(0px,5px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,5px);
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <span class="prev random-button animate go" data-go="-1" disabled>&larr;</span>
        <span class="title">TABELA</span>
        <span class="next random-button animate go" data-go="1">&rarr;</span>
    </div>
</div>

<br /><br />

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <span class="prev random-button animate go" data-go="-1" disabled>◄</span>
        <span class="title">TABELA</span>
        <span class="next random-button animate go" data-go="1">►</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ou podes até utilizar imagens como botão, como no [**exemplo do link desta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27821/11886).

Comment: Agora foi... Grato pelo ajuda, deu certo.

Answer (score -1):

Quando o input fica desativado `disabled` no atributo, por padrão CSS3, o `input` fica mais "transparente", por isso a seta que é preta virou cinza ficando um pouco mais transparente.

Para esconder o botão quando tem atributo `disabled` basta colocar esse CSS no seu site:

```
.go[disabled] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

ou deixando ele transparente por 50% (prefiro dessa forma):

```
.go[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.5; /* 50% */
}
```

Comment: a ideia dos botões deu certo, só não entendi o porque de continuar dentro dessa caixa cinza ai.

Comment: "..de continuar dentro.." não entendi, explica melhor?
Seria o porque o botão anterior continua aparecendo?

Comment: Sim... Em outro lugar funciona o desenho blz, mas quando coloco no local, a seta continua a mesma, porém só muda a cor, tipo a cor que escolhi da seta.

Comment: Tem que melhorar a sua pergunta, pois me pareceu que você pretende melhorar o estilo dos botões.
Enfim, quando o `input` fica desativado `disabled` no atributo, por padrão CSS3 nos navegadores, o `input`, fica mais "transparente", por isso a seta que é preta virou cinza ficando um pouco mais transparente.
Para esconder o elemento, basta colocar isso no seu CSS seguinte: 
`.go[disabled] { visibility: hidden }` OBS: melhorei a resposta